# I want to rewrite URL separated with (-) like aboutus to about-us.html

Tags: .htaccess

Note: My site url is :

```
http://delhincrjob.com
```

and using this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So many times I have been trying to do this but I am not able to do this this site in zend

Answer (score 0):

If its not a dynamic title, then you can do this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # If you want your aboutus page to redirect to about-us.html use the rule below
    #RewriteRule    ^aboutus/?$    about-us.html    [NC,L]

   # If you want about-us.html to open aboutus use this rule below
    RewriteRule    ^about-us.html$    aboutus    [NC,L]
```

But if its a dynamic title, like you are dependent on what is being fetch in the database. You need to rewrite your string to match your criteria like if you have a title "About us", change it to "about-us". It can be achieve by using preg_match. Then you can write your rewrite rule in your htaccess

Comment: I have try this code,but it fount this erro : Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: Ok.. so about-us.html is not an existing file? What is the file name of you about us? The rule above mean, if the url is urdomain.com/aboutus it will open the page about-us.html.

Comment: my website is make in zend framewrok so that url calling rule is :controller/method/other parameter, so that for about us page my url is http://www.delhincrjob.com/aboutus now for seo friendly i want to call it http://www.delhincrjob.com/about-us.html

Comment: I have updated my answer with a comment, # in htaccess is a comment

Comment: it also not working it think : RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]   // index routing is creating proble  if you live in ncr please give me your email id or contact no  it is urgent for me